# CSS border radius - child overlapping parent element

Tags: css

I have the following markup: http://www.webdevout.net/test?011
As you can see, the "li" element is overlapping the rounded borders defined for the box.

Is there a way to prevent this apart from applying the corner directly to the last "li"?

Thanks

Comment: "Is there a way to prevent this apart from applying the corner directly to the last "li"?" - Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the background colour to `.box` and remove the border-bottom from last `li`:

```
.box {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

#vmenu li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

On a side note, you don't need the surrounding `div`, just add the `.box` class to the `ul`.